# How can I do array mapping with response type [String]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, objectmapper, mapper

My response is same this.

```
"speed" : [ "0" , "1" , "2"]
```

current when I use **ObjectMapper** I usual map same this.

```
var speed : [String] = []

func mapping(map: Map) {
        
        speed <- map["speed"]
        
}
```

then my map is return null data.
how to map in this case.

Comment: Please drop `ObjectMapper` in favor of `Codable`.

Comment: OK let me try for a moment.

Comment: The response is not valid JSON, it must be `{"speed" : [ "0" , "1" , "2"]}`

Comment: I think problem is born in rest api haha.

Comment: I agree; better to learn Codable.